# v-for loop and use of key attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Could not frame the title more relevantly , sorry for that....

- I have an [ ] in my data property which gets filled with items with a call from external API
- I loop through the [ ]  using `v-for` on the **main div** in my template and populate the page
- there is a **toggleable div** in every **main div** which is hidden by default and is toggleable whether to display or not

**here's the code**

```
<template>

  <div>    
      // MAIN DIV
      <div v-for="(item, index) in myArray :key="index"> 
          //populate the elements using revelevant data
        <button @click="toggleDiv"">show/hide</button>

        //togglelable div
           <div v-if="displayDiv">
            //some data
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                myArray: [],
                displayDiv: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleDiv(){
                this.displayDiv = !this.displayDiv;
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

**So here's my problem**

- when i click the button in a particular div to show the hidden div, all the hidden divs of the rest all divs are also getting displayed
- how do i restrict this from happening so that only respective hidden div is toggled when respective button of that div is clicked
- should I use `key` attribute to let vue distinguish the divs or i should use any logic

Comment: Easy, make a new vue component, 'item', inside the v-for: <item :item="item"> pass the item as prop to it, then in the item component keep the displayDiv data item and its behaviour. In this way each item will have its own displayDiv (and behaviour if displayed or not).

Comment: @click="click="toggleDiv"" should be @click="toggleDiv()"

Comment: @M.Suurland i' ll try your approach

Comment: @user7814783 I will give a short example as answer.

Answer (score 4):

You must leave name of key and value like so, don't rename it.

```
<div v-for="(value, key, index) in Your-object">
  {{ index }}. {{ key }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have one property being true or false for opening all of the divs, **displayDiv**, its not *per* item.

```
    data(){
        return{
            myArray: [],
            displayDiv: false
        }
    }
```

If you can't modify the data items of the array you receiving on the remote location, then you can simply loop the items and add the property to every item once you received it.

Like this:

```
// I'll assume your api looks somewhat like this

 return axios.get('apirequest')
.then(function (res) {

// Create a new list 
var listOfItemsWithAddedProp = [];

// Loop all the items of the response..
for(var item of res.data){

    // ..and add one or multiple props
    item.open = false;

    // Then push modified item to the new list
    listOfItemsWithAddedProp.push(item);
}

// Return or set the new list to your "myArray" in your example
return listOfItemsWithAddedProp;
```

})

Answer (score 1):

Make a new component for your individual Item, and encapsulate the behaviour of showing the item or not in there.

Main component:

```
<template>

    <div v-for="item in myArray"> 
     <item :item=item>
    </div>
    ...

</template>

<script>

    import Item from './Item.vue'
    ...
    export default{
      components: {
        Item
      }
    }

</script>
```

Item component:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <button @click="toggleDiv()"">show/hide</button>
     <div v-if="displayDiv">
      ...
     </div>
  </div>
</template>



 <script>
    export default{
        props: ['item']
        data(){
            return{
                displayDiv: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleDiv(){
               this.displayDiv = !this.displayDiv;
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div v-for="(langue, index) in langues" :key="index" >
    {{langue.text}}
 </div>
```